# What's the best way to store a lot of form information on a Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I am creating a very simple web site, where you can go and register your workouts, so other people can see it and comment.

The problem is that, for example if you train 6 days a week, and do 10 exercises, I will have to store 60 exercises on Mysql.

I was thinking about creating a table with 60 rows, and then I would store all that info in there, but for some reason, this does not seems to by the best way.

So what should I do? I was looking here in Stack Overflow, and I saw something about storing this using an array and serializing it using PHP, but I'm not really sure about that.

Comment: Are you ever planning to offer the website to users other than yourself? If so, it will be more than 60 records, and MySQL is the way to go. Rather than perusing StackOverflow, read a PHP tutorial. StackOverflow is not one.

Comment: Agree with the other comment. Also, if you store it in their own rows, you can create a lot more search and report options. Otherwise, if you serialize all the data into a single field, so you're only storing maybe 10 rows, you can't really search or index the data.

Comment: If it's something trivial and very small then I would use a simple json file to store data in json format.

Comment: I assume because he says "where you can go and register your workouts, so other people can see it and comment." means it is not limited to just him

Comment: its going to be online, but after reading all the answer i gonna stick with the 60 rows, because is the only way to recreate, your training and show to other people.

Comment: This questions comes up too often. tl;dr; **Relational databases are designed for *many* records (read: rows). Use them as they want to be used.** Or (with array serialization) you're going to end with a puddle-of-goop application/model that is not scalable, is not upgradable, makes simple queries a nightmare and just a PITA to deal with.

Answer (score 4):

You should consider what a database is before worrying about this kind of problem. It is common for mysql to handle millions of entries. It is not likely you will exceed this in a normal scenario. If you did get a lot of traffic and your database grew to a point where expansion and upgrading made sense, you would consult then. For now, mysql is going to be your champion.

Serialization has its uses, but when you want to individually examine results, you will want to go with a relational design. That way you can store every bit of info on a specific workout session and give better stats to the user. Afterall, stats are addicting. Many users on this site keep coming back to build stats.

The way I read your question was that you thought storing 60 workouts individually was a lot of data. That you have a form with many fields and you want to know how to store those fields in a database in a way that makes sense. Not just for you, but for anyone that comes in and registers. Never the less, this is still a relatively small task for any database. A relational design is definitely the way to go either way.

Comment: Thanks Kai, this is exactly what i going to do!

Answer (score 2):

You should first decide logically what you want to store, and not how you store them.

Once you know what to store, then you should normalized the data to remove redundant data. This is done usually by converting the data to 3nf. See  http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

That way you can be sure that all the required data is captured.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you using the database in any case aimply because you are "storing" data. Array serializzation is not really storing data, its more of storing a piece of process for later use.

With the database you can do many more things, you might not have the fantasy right now but if one day you will have a new plan on using the data you collected you will have more space for expansion.